# Correct name for non-unit length 'hessian normal form' 3D plane.

Tags: terminology, 3d

A plane defined as 4 numbers (x,y,z,distance) is known as the *hessian normal form*, Where the `xyz` values are *unit-length*.

However I've found its not necessary to have the xyz unit length (in software I can still perform useful operations on the plane when the `xyz` vector isn't normalized, though it must be non-zero length).

This may seem obvious since its a standard representation as far as I can tell, but I want to refer to it specifically.

---

Whats the correct name/term for a plane defined by (x,y,z,distance) which isn't necessarily having a unit-length `xyz` ?

Comment: Usually, the *Normal Form* of a plane is given by $x\cdot n-p\cdot n=0$, where $n$ is a (not necessarily normed) normal vector of the plane, and $p$ is one particular point in the plane. Calling $d:=-p\cdot n$ this is equivalent to $x\cdot n+d=0$, which looks like the Hessian Normal Form.

Comment: @sranthrop, It seems your saying being unit length isn't a *requirement* ? I was going of this page as a reference which states it must be a unit normal: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HessianNormalForm.html

Comment: The thing is, that the plane itself doesn't have a name at all, but the way to define the plane has. The Hessian Normal Form has the form $x\cdot n+d=0$, where $d$ is the distance and $n$ is a normalized normal vector. However, the same plane can also be defined using the Normal Form I gave you in the before comment. So to answer your question, if the normal vector $n=(x,y,z)$ doesn't have unit length, then you have a plane in Normal Form, otherwise in Hessian Normal Form.

Comment: @sranthrop, Seems like this could be an answer.

Comment: note, wikipedia page references this as a **general form** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29

Comment: wikipedia calls it the point-normal form. The thing is, I am from Germany, and we call it just normal form. Actually, it doesn't matter how you call it as long as you define at first what you are talking about :)
If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to contact me via email. As long as I can help, I will.

Comment: I thaught point-normal was literally storing (point_xyz, normal_xyz), 2x 3d vectors. From what I can gather storing a plane as 4 numbers is so common it doesn't really have a formal name.

Comment: @sranthrop For the sake of moving this question off the unanswered list, would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is, that the plane itself doesn't have a name at all, but the way to define the plane has. The Hessian Normal Form has the form $x\cdot n+d=0$, where $d$ is the distance and $n$ is a normalized normal vector. However, the same plane can also be defined using the Normal Form I gave you in my first comment.

So to answer your question, if the normal vector $n=(x,y,z)$ doesn't have unit length, then you have a plane in **"Normal Form"**, otherwise it's **"Hessian Normal Form"**.